# jQuery TOOLS - Dateinput causes readonly textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am using the dateinput function from jQuery TOOLS. It's working fine, however the user has a requirement to enter in the date manually.

When using the dateinput method, it seems to make the textbox it's bound to read only.

How can I allow users to manually enter the date as well as use the picker control?

Comment: Can anyone help? Just come back to this issue and I can't crack it. Is it something simple?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the DateInput control.

There is an open feature request for this: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/699

Answer (score 0):

It not only makes the textbox it's bound to read only it makes all others as well. I am posting in many locations incase someone out there like me is in dire need to remove this irritating limitation.

You can see the keydown event is checking for an array of keys then is preventingDefault() on return  (thus preventing normal inputs / textareas from direct input) .

```
        d(document).on("keydown.d", function(a) {
            if (a.ctrlKey) return !0;
            var e = a.keyCode;
            if (8 == e || 46 == e) return b.val(""), f.hide(a);
            if (27 == e || 9 == e) return f.hide(a);
            if (0 <= d(Q).index(e)) {
                if (!u) return f.show(a), a.preventDefault();
                var h = d("#" + c.weeks + " a"),
                    j = d("." + c.focus),
                    g = h.index(j);
                j.removeClass(c.focus);
                if (74 == e || 40 == e) g += 7;
                else if (75 == e || 38 == e) g -= 7;
                else if (76 == e || 39 == e) g += 1;
                else if (72 == e || 37 == e) g -= 1;
                41 < g ? (f.addMonth(), j = d("#" + c.weeks + " a:eq(" +
                    (g - 42) + ")")) : 0 > g ? (f.addMonth(-1), j = d("#" + c.weeks + " a:eq(" + (g + 42) + ")")) : j = h.eq(g);
                j.addClass(c.focus);
                return a.preventDefault()
            }
            if (34 == e) return f.addMonth();
            if (33 == e) return f.addMonth(-1);
            if (36 == e) return f.today();
            13 == e && (d(a.target).is("select") || d("." + c.focus).click());
            return 0 <= d([16,17,18,9]).index(e)
        });
```

I was able to remove the code from the minified source but I lost the compression in doing so. I have yet to see any negative affects (other then the file size was 42kb => 140kb).